# Como generar html's con datos variables

Tags: javascript, python, html5, json, variables

Tengo un código html, que pretendo usar como plantilla y deseo reemplazar datos y que se genere un html con un nombre único por cada archivo, pero no se como hacerlo, descarte `php` ya que es para uso laboral y donde me encuentro no permiten el uso de php.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DISH TE INVITA AL CINE</title>  
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('require', 'displayfeatures');
  gtag('config', 'UA-140129501-1');
</script>

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icodish.png">   
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script><![endif]-->

  <style> 
  .container{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.name-user{
    position: absolute;
    top: 560px;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
.thx{
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
.print{
    position: absolute;
    top: 660px;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
.fol1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 760px;
    left: calc(35% - 60px); 
    width:100%;
}
.fol2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 760px;
    left: calc(35% - 350px); 
    width:100%;
}
.acude{
    position: absolute;
    top: 710px;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
.resti{
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
.date{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1016px;
    left: calc(35% - 120px); 
    width:100%;
}
.centrado{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(95% - 15px);
 }>
</style>
  </head>
<body>
  <center>
    <div class="container" align="center">
       <img src="img/TRADICIONAL.png" width="600" />
       <td><div class="name-user"> <span style="font-size:20pt;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#fff"><b>Por ser un empleado cumplido, Gracias.</b></span></div></td>
       <td><div class="thx"> <span style="font-size:20pt;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#efb810">TE REGALAMOS DOS BOLETOS<br/>PARA IR AL CINE</span></div></td>
       <td><div class="print"> <span style="font-size:16pt;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#fff">Canjea en Linea o Presenta en Sucursal<br/>tus folios para hacerlos válidos</span></div></td>
       <td><div class="acude"> <span style="font-size:10pt;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#fff">Acude de lunes a viernes a cualquier CINÉPOLIS TRADICIONAL de tu ciudad.</span></div></td>
       <td><div align="center" class="fol1"> <span style="font-size:14pt;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000"><b>1158685823145</b></span></div></td>
       <td><div align="center" class="fol2"> <span style="font-size:14pt;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000"><b>1234567890123</b></span></div></td>
       <td><div class="resti"> <span style="font-size:6pt;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#efb810"><p>RESTRICCIONES: No válido en Cinépolis VIP, IMAX, Funciones 3D, 4Dx, Macro XE, Sala Plus, Sala Junior o Cinema Park.</p><p> El folio debe presentarse completo en taquilla para que pueda ser reconocido por el sistema. El beneficio lo posee el portador del folio y es válido una sola vez.</p><p>El folio no aplica en días de descanso obligatorio señalados en la Ley Federal del Trabajo. Válido de lunes a viernes. No aplica con otras promociones.</p><p> No aplica en premieres, funciones especiales o contenido alternativo. No aplica en reservaciones por Cineticket o venta avanzada.</p><p> Sujeto a disponibilidad o cupo de la película. Por seguridad de la empresa, Cinépolis se reserva el derecho de admisión.</p></span></div></td>
       <td><div align="center" class="date"> <span style="font-size:16pt;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000"><b>02/10/2019 al 05/12/2019</b></span></div></td>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Ese es el código del archivo html, es una plantilla para envío de folios para cine, los cuales serán cambiantes, y el archivo html tendrá el nombre del empleado, ya que lo quieren personalizado.

Si me pudieran ayudar; es que realmente intente ya varias cosas y no sale.

Gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python tiene [jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/) que es un lenguaje de plantillas, que usa una sintaxis específica dentro de la plantilla, la cual puede ser un fichero html, texto plano o realmente cualquier otra cosa, con tal de que use la sintaxis jinja para marcar dónde irían las variables Python.

Las funciones de jinja te permiten cargar esa plantilla desde un archivo (o tenerla declarada en una cadena python, como prefieras), y "renderizarla", esto es, reemplazar las zonas marcadas con la sintaxis especial por los valores de variables Python. Estas variables pueden ser cadenas, enteros, o incluso listas (y la plantilla puede contener "bucles" que desenrollarían la lista para mostrar todos sus valores), diccionarios u objetos con campos a los que podrías acceder con la notación punto.

En tu caso no está claro qué información es la que sería variable dentro de la plantilla, pero voy a ponerte un ejemplo que podrías fácilmente adaptar a tus necesidades.

Supongamos, para simplificar, que la plantilla es texto plano (en vez de HTML) y que simplemente necesitas mostrar en ella variables sencillas, como `nombre`, y `apellidos`, junto con un `genero` que puede ser "o" (masculino) o "a" (femenino). Jinja usa doble llave alrededor de los elementos "a sustituir". La plantilla podría ser esta:

```
plantilla = """
Estimad{{genero}} {{nombre}},

Enhorabuena, has sido agraciad{{genero}} con dos entradas de cine
a nombre de {{nombre}} {{apellidos}} que podrás retirar en bla bla...

Esperamos verte pronto, {{nombre}}!
"""
```

Si queremos "renderizar"  esta plantilla para diferenets nombres y guardar el resultado de cada una en un fichero diferente, podemos tener una estructura de datos, tal como una lista de diccionarios. Cada elemento de la lista dará lugar a un fichero. Los elementos del diccionario pueden ser el nombre, apellidos, genero y nombre de fichero a generar. Harías entonces así:

```
from jinja2 import Template

datos = [
{ "nombre": "Juan", "apellidos": "Fernández", "genero": "o", "fichero": "00000.txt" },
{ "nombre": "Ana", "apellidos": "García", "genero": "a", "fichero": "00001.txt" },
{ "nombre": "José", "apellidos": "López", "genero": "o", "fichero": "00002.txt" },
]

for persona in datos:
  result = Template(plantilla).render(**persona)
  with open(persona["fichero"], "w") as f:
     f.write(result)
```

En este ejemplo se generarían los ficheros `00000.txt`, `00001.txt` y `000002.txt`, cada uno con contenidos personalizados.

Comment: Hola muy buenas tardes, Excelente tu código, no lo conocía, lo estoy probando y funciona muy bien pero tengo algunas dudas si puedes ayudarme.

tomando tu ejemplo en lugar de que los datos estén en dentro del archivo que los tome de otro archivo, por ejemplo un json ya que veo que es el formato de json y en lugar de ser como en tu ejemplo sea :

datos = datos.json
o algo similar se podrá?

y otra cosa estoy teniendo problemas con los acentos no me los muestra me marca este símbolo �

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: para leer de un json debes usar `import json`, leer el contenido del archivo (que una vez leído será una cadena) y después hacer `datos = json.loads(cadena)` para que te lo convierta en un diccionario python como los que usé en mi código. Respecto a los símbolos de los acentos, se deben a que el fichero del que lees está codificado en "latin1" en vez de "utf-8". ¿Estás usando python2?

Comment: Hola ok intentare lo del json espero me funcione
no estoy usando python 3.7.4

Comment: Si encuentras problemas con el json o con los acentos, lo mejor sería que abrieras otra pregunta, pues en los comentarios no hay mucho sitio para explicarse. Por otro lado, si esta respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada para que la pregunta quede resuelta

Comment: me ayudaste bastante te lo agradezco, sobre el otro tema lo pude resolver fue mas fácil de lo que pensé muchas gracias.